# How to execute the go test file in the goeclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, testing, go

How do I create a eclipse launch file to execute the test file or run configuration in the goeclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an enhancement which is pending: [issue 5](https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/issues/5)

> I was thinking more along the line of adding a menu item ("Test go application") in the "`run as`" context menu.
>
> Right now if I select a go test file and click "Run go application" from the "run as" context menu nothing is executed (no main).
>
> A "Test go application" could do a "go test" on the file instead of a "go run"...

For now, there is only an option "Enable continuous testing":

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9b9a724f67e9a7567736fba03d60943768b18c50/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f573567446258302e706e67]

Comment: So the new release of goeclipse will include this enhancement?

Comment: @wingwing I suppose so, if a contributor provides a PR (Pull Request)